# How to work with the new Android ICS desktop shortcut folders from code?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I need the ability to create, modify, and delete the desktop shortcut folders that are new to ICS. I've found examples on how to create application shortcuts (of course), but I can't find any information on how to work with the new ICS folders. Anyone have any idea?

I'm using your standard Eclipse-based Java development environment; I would expect that the `com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT` intent action would be used, but I have no idea where to go from there...

Thanks in advance!

Jason

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is the following:

Android 1.0 - 2.x
Uses [Live Folders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/LiveFolders.html)

Android 3.0+
Uses [App Widgets with Collections](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections)

From there to what you would like to accomplish, best of luck to you! :)

Comment: Thanks Asok, App Widgets with Collections sounds like a step in the right direction.  Though I still don't see any info on exactly how to talk to the built-in ICS app folders; only how to program my own by creating a widget. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: I am VERY unclear on what you are specifically trying to accomplish, creating and deleting folders is simple.. If you're talking about manipulating how the Launcher handles folder then to be honest, I don't think what you are asking is possible. The Launcher is an app of it's own, unless you make a Launcher of your own I don't believe you can manipulate how the stock Launcher creates, modifies or deletes their folders. I can't see any reason why you couldn't make an app that adds a similar folder widget and then make the appropriate modifications that you're looking for.

Comment: No, actually all I need to do is create and remove folders, not change how the launcher behaves. Feels like maybe I'm missing something, but the link you referenced for Android 3.0+ only tells me how to program my own widgets, not how to add and remove shortcut folders on the Android 4.0 desktop.